# Publish Web.Release.config to IIS from VS, web deploy, one-click publish

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-deployment

I have a few appSetting entries in my web.config.

I have some different entries in web.Release.config that I would like to push to IIS(7) when 
I publish. (I am publishing using the one-click publish in VS2010 using the web deploy method).

When I publish to IIS and run the app, the app is getting the values from web.config and not web.release.config.

(I am in the Release configuration when I publish).

What am I missing ?

[EDIT]

The app settings section of the web.release.config:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="StylesheetPath" value="http://mySite/Stylesheet/"/>
    <add key="ImagePath" value="http://mySite/Stylesheet/images/"/>
  </appSettings>
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you post a portion of your web.release.config file? I'd like to see appSettings node (if that's the one that your values are contained within)

Comment: Sure thing, added to the original post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your web.release.config's appSettings node, add a transform attribute

```
<appSettings xdt:Transform="Replace">
<add key="StylesheetPath" value="http://mySite/Stylesheet/"/>
<add key="ImagePath" value="http://mySite/Stylesheet/images/"/>
</appSettings>
```

This xdt:Transform tells the config builder to take the appSettings node in your web.config and replace it with this one. When you deploy it, the web.config should be updated.

Comment: Did that work okay? More information on the transforms can be found here: http://weblogs.asp.net/srkirkland/archive/2009/10/13/common-web-config-transformations-with-visual-studio-2010.aspx

Comment: Yes that did exactly what i wanted. Love the one click publish, this is a nice added feature for quick and painless deployment to dev servers. Thanks again for such a quick answer.

Comment: Once they integrate it into Azure Publishing, I'll be especially happy!

Comment: so I gather that the two files (web.config and web.release.config) get uploaded to IIS.  and if I had a web.debug.config, that would get uploaded too... but how does IIS know which to pick (debug vs. release)?

Comment: It's actually the deployment that does the transformation based on the build configuration.

Comment: Make sure to also include xml-namespace in configuration-element like shown here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/web-config-transformations
`<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">`